# Match ARSCNView transforms for custom Scenekit rendering?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

#### TL:DR

I am trying to render an `SCNRenderer` in a `MTKView` so I have handles on the color / depth buffers - and I am trying to match the transforms that `ARSCNView` does via `ARKit` so my `SCNRenderer` behaves like an ARSCNView.

Does anyone have an example of matching ARSCNViews world and face tracking configurations via the `ARFrame`/`ARCamera` and info provided by `ARKit` - and properly modifying the transforms of `SCNSCamera` appropriately?

#### Longer

For various reasons (not having access to a `MTLPassDescriptor` for `ARSCNView` / `SCNView` and `SCNTechnique` having its own weird limitations) I'm trying to re-implement some of `ARSCNView` via `MTKView` + `ARKit` + `SCNRenderer` myself, which allows me to have more control over the rendering pipeline. I am basing my code off of Apples ARKit + Metal example.

I'd like to match what `ARKit` is doing - but when I attempt to use the `ARFrame` / `ARCamera` information to modify my `SCNScene` and `SCNCamera` as I show below, my scene moves, but not with the camera in the same way that either `ARSCNView` or the ARKit with Metal demo does.

I'm at a loss as to what is incorrectly being passed to my scene from ARKit.

My Scene:

```
self.sceneKitRenderer = SCNRenderer(device: self.device, options: nil)

self.sceneKitRenderer?.delegate = self as SCNSceneRendererDelegate


let scene = SCNScene()
scene.background.contents = nil

let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
sphere.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0.0, -5)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)


let camera = SCNCamera()
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
cameraNode.look(at: scene.rootNode.worldPosition)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

self.sceneKitRenderer?.scene = scene
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView = cameraNode
```

I am updating my Scene's point of view and its projection matrix when I receive an updated ARFrame like so:

```
// Match clipping
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.camera?.zNear = 0.001
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.camera?.zFar = 1000

// Match projection
let projection = SCNMatrix4( frame.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .landscapeRight, viewportSize: viewportSize, zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000))
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.camera?.projectionTransform = projection

// Match transform
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.simdTransform = frame.camera.transform
```

While this appears to do something, it isn't matching ARKits output.

Questions:

Is assigning the `simdTransform` or the `SCNRenderer`'s `pointOfView`  from the camera's translation correct?

Do I need to do something to my scene to set up the proper coordinate system (ie, a root node scale?)

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I did two things to get this working.
First you need to get the camera node from ARKit's scene and use this to set the camera node's `transform` and the camera's `projectionTransform` in your other scene:

```
// get the first node that has a camera attached
if let arkitCameraNode = arkitScene.rootNode.childNodes(passingTest: { (node, stop) -> Bool in
     return node.camera != nil
}).first {
     // SCNNode
     otherSceneCameraNode.transform = arkitCameraNode.transform
     // SCNCamera
     otherSceneCamera.projectionTransform = arkitCameraNode.camera!.projectionTransform
}
```

After this you need to sync the cloned nodes in your other scene by getting its corresponding `ARAnchor` transform:

```
if let anchor = arkitSceneView.anchor(for: nodeFromARKitScene) {
     clonedNodeInOtherScene.simdTransform = anchor.transform
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this. Im actually not using an ARSCNView at all - so I dont have a reference scene with transforms to copy. However my above code does work, its just that the coordinate system was not what I expected - and once I began using meters in my scene it worked itself out :)

Answer (score 2):

The code referenced in the question for matching the `ARCamera` with the SCNScene camera won't work for different orientations, as the transform will differ depending on the orientation. There is a function on `ARCamera` to get the view matrix for a particular orientation(the view matrix being the inverse of the camera transform). So the following can be used to correctly take orientation in to account:

```
// Match clipping
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.camera?.zNear = 0.001
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.camera?.zFar = 1000

// Match projection
let projection = SCNMatrix4( frame.camera.projectionMatrix(for: .portrait, viewportSize: viewportSize, zNear: 0.001, zFar: 1000))
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.camera?.projectionTransform = projection

// Match transform
self.sceneKitRenderer?.pointOfView?.simdTransform = currentFrame.camera.viewMatrix(for: .portrait).inverse
```